# Custom number of scrolling lines

Tags: mouse, macos

I recently purchased a MacBook Pro 2016 13″, my first Apple laptop. I'm using an Evoluent Vertical Mouse 4 due to repetitive strain injuries. I find that scrolling on OS X was an excruciating process for me.

I prefer setting the scroll wheel to scroll a large number of lines per tick (ie. 12-15). This minimizes the strain on my tendons. I prefer having either no acceleration or having acceleration kick in only after scrolling very quickly.

After searching around, SmoothScroll was a perfect solution, allowing for scrolling by # of pixels with custom acceleration settings. However, are there any free options that would fit the bill?